Riemann tensor from tetrad formalism
I would like to write a Mathematica notebook to perform a repetitive tensorial calculation.
In particular, I am trying to compute the Riemann tensor for a given metric using the tetrad formalism. I used Cartan's structure equation to calculate the curvature 2-form $\Omega^{a}_{b}$, from which it is possible to read the coeffiecients $\Omega^{a}_{bcd}$ by setting
$\Omega^{a}_{b}=\Omega^{a}_{bcd}e^{c}\wedge e^{d},$
where $e^{a}$, $a=\{0,1,2,3\}$, are the elements of the tetrad.
The Riemann tensor is then given by
$R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=\Omega_{abcd}e^{a}_{\mu}e^{b}_{\nu}e^{c}_{\rho}e^{d}_{\sigma},$
with $\{\mu,\nu,\rho,\sigma\}=\{t,z,r,\phi\}$.
Is there a way to write a notebook that takes $\Omega_{abcd}$ and the tetrad and gives the Riemann tensor components?
Additional details:
the tetrad components are $e^{\mu}_{0}=(e^{t}_{0},e^{z}_{0},e^{r}_{0},e^{\phi}_{0})$, $e^{\mu}_{1}=(e^{t}_{1},e^{z}_{1},e^{r}_{1},e^{\phi}_{1})$,
$e^{\mu}_{2}=(e^{t}_{2},e^{z}_{2},e^{r}_{2},e^{\phi}_{2})$,
$e^{\mu}_{3}=(e^{t}_{3},e^{z}_{3},e^{r}_{3},e^{\phi}_{3})$, with all the components already calculated.
$\Omega_{abcd}$, with {a,b,c,d}={0,1,2,3}, are 20 independent coefficients that I have already calculated.
To obtain the Riemann tensor I have to perform the operation above, that is a contraction of the indeces {a,b,c,d}={0,1,2,3} between the curvature coefficients and the tetrad components.
In simple words: I am trying to calculate the components of the Riemann tensor in a given coordinate system.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
